# How do I get multiple actions and state with Vuex namespaced modules and the Vue Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

With the Vue Options API I get my actions and state by doing:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState("myStore", ["myState", "myOtherState"]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("myStore", ["myAction", "myOtherAction"]),
  }
```

My question is how do I get multiple namespaced actions and state with Vuex and the Vue Composition API?
Right now I have a wrapper called useStoreModule.js that looks like this:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from "vuex-composition-helpers/dist";

export default function () {
  function getState(module, name) {
    const { useState } = createNamespacedHelpers(module);
    return useState([name]);
  }
  function getAction(module, name) {
    const { useActions } = createNamespacedHelpers(module);
    return useActions([name]);
  }
  return {
    getState,
    getAction,
  };
}
```

and get the state/actions by doing this:

```
setup() {
    const { getState } = useStoreModule();
    const { myState } = getState("myStore", "myState");
}
```

So how do I write the wrapper to do this:

```
setup() {
    const { getState } = useStoreModule();
    const { myState, myOtherState, myOtherOtherState } = getState("myStore", ["myState", "myOtherState", "myOtherOtherState"]);
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

`component.vue`

```
  import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

  setup() {
    const _instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const { $store } = _instance.appContext.app.config.globalProperties;
  },
```

`createStore`

```
"use strict";
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

// Stores
import moduleA from '@/store/moduleA.js';
import moduleB from '@/store/moduleB.js';

export const store = createStore({
  strict: true,
  modules: {
    moduleA,
    moduleB,
  }
});
```